# Pictures/site are not showing properly in versions of IE lower than 10 with Bootstrap template

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, bootstrap, browser

I stumbled across a strange thing. The site I develop uses the **Bootstrap Framework**. 
Recently the friend, for which I make the site, pointed out that the pictures on one of the pages are extremely large ..
It appears she uses the "older" version of IE, namely version 8 and indeed the site does not display correctly. It is not the case when using IE 10 or 11, chrome or FF.

I have now tried everything, even changing the pictures from jpg to png and that seems to be a bit better, but still the width is totally ignored.

I am sure it's in the bootstrap files, but can't find the reason for this behaviour (nor the solution to this).

Has anybody an idea about how to solve this?

For those amongst you who want to take a look, test site is www.webmatix.be/nikie.

There click on Enter Site and choose from the menu "Wie ik ben"
The top picture displays correctly, the three pictures underneath the text do not.

Answer (score 2):

To get Bootstrap working on older browsers such as IE8, we must import a script called **respond.js**. I think the reason why your images aren't displaying as they should is because they aren't sitting within the grid due to the fact that **respond.js** *isn't* being imported. If you look at the inspector, it's trying to be called from here:

```
/nikie/templates/artwork4template/js/respond.min.js
```

But the file doesn't exist. Sort this out and see if the problem still persists.